# MISTY1 Implementation error

Tags: implementation

I am trying to implement MISTY1. It's RFC, [RFC2994](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2994), contains psuedocode that I basically copy and pasted into Code::Blocks. However, I managed to mess that up somehow. After 2 days, I still have not figured out what i did wrong (Im probably being blinded by familiarity).

The RFC provides 2 test vectors, but only the key, plaintext and ciphertext. it does not provide internal values of any sort, and i cannot find other examples of calculations.

I can decrypt incorrectly encrypted data, so i suspect the error is in the key scheduling part, but I have no values to test with.

Can someone see where I made a mistake with the algorithm?

```
class MISTY1{
    private:
        bool keyset;
        uint16_t EK[32];
        uint8_t S7TABLE[128];
        uint16_t S9TABLE[512];
 
        uint16_t FI(uint16_t FI_IN, uint16_t FI_KEY){
            uint16_t d9 = FI_IN >> 7;
            uint16_t d7 = FI_IN & 0x7f;
            d9 = S9TABLE[d9] ^ d7;
            d7 = S7TABLE[d7] ^ d9;
//            ( d7 = d7 & 0x7f; )
            d7 = d7 ^ (FI_KEY >> 9);
            d9 = d9 ^ (FI_KEY & 0x1ff);
            d9 = S9TABLE[d9] ^ d7;
            return ((uint16_t) (d7 && 0xffffU) << 9) | d9;
        }
 
        uint32_t FO(uint32_t FO_IN, uint16_t k){
            uint16_t t0 = FO_IN >> 16;
            uint16_t t1 = FO_IN & 0xffff;
            t0 = t0 ^ EK[k];
            t0 = FI(t0, EK[(k+5)%8+8]);
            t0 = t0 ^ t1;
            t1 = t1 ^ EK[(k+2)%8];
            t1 = FI(t1, EK[(k+1)%8+8]);
            t1 = t1 ^ t0;
            t0 = t0 ^ EK[(k+7)%8];
            t0 = FI(t0, EK[(k+3)%8+8]);
            t0 = t0 ^ t1;
            t1 = t1 ^ EK[(k+4)%8];
            return (t1 << 16) | t0;
        }
 
        uint32_t FL(uint32_t FL_IN, uint32_t k){
            uint16_t d0 = FL_IN >> 16;
            uint16_t d1 = FL_IN & 0xffff;
            if (!(k & 1)){
               d1 = d1 ^ (d0 & EK[k/2]);
               d0 = d0 ^ (d1 | EK[(k/2+6)%8+8]);
            }
            else{
               d1 = d1 ^ (d0 & EK[((k-1)/2+2)%8+8]);
               d0 = d0 ^ (d1 | EK[((k-1)/2+4)%8]);
            }
            return (d0 << 16) | d1;
        }
 
        uint32_t FLINV(uint32_t FL_IN, uint32_t k){
            uint16_t d0 = FL_IN >> 16;
            uint16_t d1 = FL_IN & 0xffff;
            if (!(k & 1)){
               d0 = d0 ^ (d1 | EK[(k/2+6)%8+8]);
               d1 = d1 ^ (d0 & EK[k/2]);
            }
            else{
               d0 = d0 ^ (d1 | EK[((k-1)/2+4)%8]);
               d1 = d1 ^ (d0 & EK[((k-1)/2+2)%8+8]);
            }
            return (d0 << 16) | d1;
        }
 
    public:
        MISTY1() : keyset(false) {}
 
        MISTY1(std::string key){
            keyset = false;
            setkey(key);
        }
 
        void setkey(std::string key){
            if (keyset)
                exit(2);
            uint8_t S7[128] = { 0x1b, 0x32, 0x33, 0x5a, 0x3b, 0x10, 0x17, 0x54, 0x5b, 0x1a, 0x72, 0x73, 0x6b, 0x2c, 0x66, 0x49,
                                0x1f, 0x24, 0x13, 0x6c, 0x37, 0x2e, 0x3f, 0x4a, 0x5d, 0x0f, 0x40, 0x56, 0x25, 0x51, 0x1c, 0x04,
                                0x0b, 0x46, 0x20, 0x0d, 0x7b, 0x35, 0x44, 0x42, 0x2b, 0x1e, 0x41, 0x14, 0x4b, 0x79, 0x15, 0x6f,
                                0x0e, 0x55, 0x09, 0x36, 0x74, 0x0c, 0x67, 0x53, 0x28, 0x0a, 0x7e, 0x38, 0x02, 0x07, 0x60, 0x29,
                                0x19, 0x12, 0x65, 0x2f, 0x30, 0x39, 0x08, 0x68, 0x5f, 0x78, 0x2a, 0x4c, 0x64, 0x45, 0x75, 0x3d,
                                0x59, 0x48, 0x03, 0x57, 0x7c, 0x4f, 0x62, 0x3c, 0x1d, 0x21, 0x5e, 0x27, 0x6a, 0x70, 0x4d, 0x3a,
                                0x01, 0x6d, 0x6e, 0x63, 0x18, 0x77, 0x23, 0x05, 0x26, 0x76, 0x00, 0x31, 0x2d, 0x7a, 0x7f, 0x61,
                                0x50, 0x22, 0x11, 0x06, 0x47, 0x16, 0x52, 0x4e, 0x71, 0x3e, 0x69, 0x43, 0x34, 0x5c, 0x58, 0x7d};
 
            uint16_t S9[512] = {0x1c3, 0x0cb, 0x153, 0x19f, 0x1e3, 0x0e9, 0x0fb, 0x035, 0x181, 0x0b9, 0x117, 0x1eb, 0x133, 0x009, 0x02d, 0x0d3,
                                0x0c7, 0x14a, 0x037, 0x07e, 0x0eb, 0x164, 0x193, 0x1d8, 0x0a3, 0x11e, 0x055, 0x02c, 0x01d, 0x1a2, 0x163, 0x118,
                                0x14b, 0x152, 0x1d2, 0x00f, 0x02b, 0x030, 0x13a, 0x0e5, 0x111, 0x138, 0x18e, 0x063, 0x0e3, 0x0c8, 0x1f4, 0x01b,
                                0x001, 0x09d, 0x0f8, 0x1a0, 0x16d, 0x1f3, 0x01c, 0x146, 0x07d, 0x0d1, 0x082, 0x1ea, 0x183, 0x12d, 0x0f4, 0x19e,
                                0x1d3, 0x0dd, 0x1e2, 0x128, 0x1e0, 0x0ec, 0x059, 0x091, 0x011, 0x12f, 0x026, 0x0dc, 0x0b0, 0x18c, 0x10f, 0x1f7,
                                0x0e7, 0x16c, 0x0b6, 0x0f9, 0x0d8, 0x151, 0x101, 0x14c, 0x103, 0x0b8, 0x154, 0x12b, 0x1ae, 0x017, 0x071, 0x00c,
                                0x047, 0x058, 0x07f, 0x1a4, 0x134, 0x129, 0x084, 0x15d, 0x19d, 0x1b2, 0x1a3, 0x048, 0x07c, 0x051, 0x1ca, 0x023,
                                0x13d, 0x1a7, 0x165, 0x03b, 0x042, 0x0da, 0x192, 0x0ce, 0x0c1, 0x06b, 0x09f, 0x1f1, 0x12c, 0x184, 0x0fa, 0x196,
                                0x1e1, 0x169, 0x17d, 0x031, 0x180, 0x10a, 0x094, 0x1da, 0x186, 0x13e, 0x11c, 0x060, 0x175, 0x1cf, 0x067, 0x119,
                                0x065, 0x068, 0x099, 0x150, 0x008, 0x007, 0x17c, 0x0b7, 0x024, 0x019, 0x0de, 0x127, 0x0db, 0x0e4, 0x1a9, 0x052,
                                0x109, 0x090, 0x19c, 0x1c1, 0x028, 0x1b3, 0x135, 0x16a, 0x176, 0x0df, 0x1e5, 0x188, 0x0c5, 0x16e, 0x1de, 0x1b1,
                                0x0c3, 0x1df, 0x036, 0x0ee, 0x1ee, 0x0f0, 0x093, 0x049, 0x09a, 0x1b6, 0x069, 0x081, 0x125, 0x00b, 0x05e, 0x0b4,
                                0x149, 0x1c7, 0x174, 0x03e, 0x13b, 0x1b7, 0x08e, 0x1c6, 0x0ae, 0x010, 0x095, 0x1ef, 0x04e, 0x0f2, 0x1fd, 0x085,
                                0x0fd, 0x0f6, 0x0a0, 0x16f, 0x083, 0x08a, 0x156, 0x09b, 0x13c, 0x107, 0x167, 0x098, 0x1d0, 0x1e9, 0x003, 0x1fe,
                                0x0bd, 0x122, 0x089, 0x0d2, 0x18f, 0x012, 0x033, 0x06a, 0x142, 0x0ed, 0x170, 0x11b, 0x0e2, 0x14f, 0x158, 0x131,
                                0x147, 0x05d, 0x113, 0x1cd, 0x079, 0x161, 0x1a5, 0x179, 0x09e, 0x1b4, 0x0cc, 0x022, 0x132, 0x01a, 0x0e8, 0x004,
                                0x187, 0x1ed, 0x197, 0x039, 0x1bf, 0x1d7, 0x027, 0x18b, 0x0c6, 0x09c, 0x0d0, 0x14e, 0x06c, 0x034, 0x1f2, 0x06e,
                                0x0ca, 0x025, 0x0ba, 0x191, 0x0fe, 0x013, 0x106, 0x02f, 0x1ad, 0x172, 0x1db, 0x0c0, 0x10b, 0x1d6, 0x0f5, 0x1ec,
                                0x10d, 0x076, 0x114, 0x1ab, 0x075, 0x10c, 0x1e4, 0x159, 0x054, 0x11f, 0x04b, 0x0c4, 0x1be, 0x0f7, 0x029, 0x0a4,
                                0x00e, 0x1f0, 0x077, 0x04d, 0x17a, 0x086, 0x08b, 0x0b3, 0x171, 0x0bf, 0x10e, 0x104, 0x097, 0x15b, 0x160, 0x168,
                                0x0d7, 0x0bb, 0x066, 0x1ce, 0x0fc, 0x092, 0x1c5, 0x06f, 0x016, 0x04a, 0x0a1, 0x139, 0x0af, 0x0f1, 0x190, 0x00a,
                                0x1aa, 0x143, 0x17b, 0x056, 0x18d, 0x166, 0x0d4, 0x1fb, 0x14d, 0x194, 0x19a, 0x087, 0x1f8, 0x123, 0x0a7, 0x1b8,
                                0x141, 0x03c, 0x1f9, 0x140, 0x02a, 0x155, 0x11a, 0x1a1, 0x198, 0x0d5, 0x126, 0x1af, 0x061, 0x12e, 0x157, 0x1dc,
                                0x072, 0x18a, 0x0aa, 0x096, 0x115, 0x0ef, 0x045, 0x07b, 0x08d, 0x145, 0x053, 0x05f, 0x178, 0x0b2, 0x02e, 0x020,
                                0x1d5, 0x03f, 0x1c9, 0x1e7, 0x1ac, 0x044, 0x038, 0x014, 0x0b1, 0x16b, 0x0ab, 0x0b5, 0x05a, 0x182, 0x1c8, 0x1d4,
                                0x018, 0x177, 0x064, 0x0cf, 0x06d, 0x100, 0x199, 0x130, 0x15a, 0x005, 0x120, 0x1bb, 0x1bd, 0x0e0, 0x04f, 0x0d6,
                                0x13f, 0x1c4, 0x12a, 0x015, 0x006, 0x0ff, 0x19b, 0x0a6, 0x043, 0x088, 0x050, 0x15f, 0x1e8, 0x121, 0x073, 0x17e,
                                0x0bc, 0x0c2, 0x0c9, 0x173, 0x189, 0x1f5, 0x074, 0x1cc, 0x1e6, 0x1a8, 0x195, 0x01f, 0x041, 0x00d, 0x1ba, 0x032,
                                0x03d, 0x1d1, 0x080, 0x0a8, 0x057, 0x1b9, 0x162, 0x148, 0x0d9, 0x105, 0x062, 0x07a, 0x021, 0x1ff, 0x112, 0x108,
                                0x1c0, 0x0a9, 0x11d, 0x1b0, 0x1a6, 0x0cd, 0x0f3, 0x05c, 0x102, 0x05b, 0x1d9, 0x144, 0x1f6, 0x0ad, 0x0a5, 0x03a,
                                0x1cb, 0x136, 0x17f, 0x046, 0x0e1, 0x01e, 0x1dd, 0x0e6, 0x137, 0x1fa, 0x185, 0x08c, 0x08f, 0x040, 0x1b5, 0x0be,
                                0x078, 0x000, 0x0ac, 0x110, 0x15e, 0x124, 0x002, 0x1bc, 0x0a2, 0x0ea, 0x070, 0x1fc, 0x116, 0x15c, 0x04c, 0x1c2};
            for(uint8_t i = 0; i < 128; i++)
                S7TABLE[i] = S7[i];
            for(uint16_t i = 0; i < 512; i++)
                S9TABLE[i] = S9[i];
            for(uint8_t i = 0; i < 8; i++)
                EK[i] = ((key[i*2]*256) & 0xffff) + (key[i*2+1] & 0xff);
            for(uint8_t i = 0; i < 8; i++){
                EK[i+ 8] = FI(EK[i], EK[(i+1)%8]);
                EK[i+16] = EK[i+8] & 0x1ff;
                EK[i+24] = EK[i+8] >> 9;
            }
            keyset = true;
        }
 
        std::string encrypt(std::string data){
            if (!keyset)
                exit(1);
            uint32_t D0 = toint(data.substr(0, 4), 256);
            uint32_t D1 = toint(data.substr(4, 4), 256);
            // 0 round
            D0 = FL(D0, 0);
            D1 = FL(D1, 1);
            D1 = D1 ^ FO(D0, 0);
            // 1 round
            D0 = D0 ^ FO(D1, 1);
            // 2 round
            D0 = FL(D0, 2);
            D1 = FL(D1, 3);
            D1 = D1 ^ FO(D0, 2);
            // 3 round
            D0 = D0 ^ FO(D1, 3);
            // 4 round
            D0 = FL(D0, 4);
            D1 = FL(D1, 5);
            D1 = D1 ^ FO(D0, 4);
            // 5 round
            D0 = D0 ^ FO(D1, 5);
            // 6 round
            D0 = FL(D0, 6);
            D1 = FL(D1, 7);
            D1 = D1 ^ FO(D0, 6);
            // 7 round
            D0 = D0 ^ FO(D1, 7);
            // final
            D0 = FL(D0, 8);
            D1 = FL(D1, 9);
            return unhexlify(makehex(D1, 8) + makehex(D0, 8));
        }
 
        std::string decrypt(std::string data){
            if (!keyset)
                exit(1);
            uint32_t D0 = toint(data.substr(4, 4), 256);
            uint32_t D1 = toint(data.substr(0, 4), 256);
            D0 = FLINV(D0, 8);
            D1 = FLINV(D1, 9);
            D0 = D0 ^ FO(D1, 7);
            D1 = D1 ^ FO(D0, 6);
            D0 = FLINV(D0, 6);
            D1 = FLINV(D1, 7);
            D0 = D0 ^ FO(D1, 5);
            D1 = D1 ^ FO(D0, 4);
            D0 = FLINV(D0, 4);
            D1 = FLINV(D1, 5);
            D0 = D0 ^ FO(D1, 3);
            D1 = D1 ^ FO(D0, 2);
            D0 = FLINV(D0, 2);
            D1 = FLINV(D1, 3);
            D0 = D0 ^ FO(D1, 1);
            D1 = D1 ^ FO(D0, 0);
            D0 = FLINV(D0, 0);
            D1 = FLINV(D1, 1);
            return unhexlify(makehex(D0, 8) + makehex(D1));
        }
};
```

What did I manage to do wrong?

The full code is at http://ideone.com/RC8Z7 . the test vector (in the main function) provided contained 2 blocks of data. i just encrypted the first block. the second block is commented out. the functions not in `class MISTY1` have been used for quite some time and are of no concern. They are there to tell you what they do

Edit: I have looked at other implementations, and I seem to be doing the same things they do, and yet I'm not getting correct outputs.

EDIT: After fixing the && bug, it is still not correct: http://ideone.com/nV8un

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation of `FI()` looks suspect to me.  I'm pretty sure `d7` is supposed to be a 7-bit value, but you store it in a 16-bit value.  This means that, after any operation that could set higher bits of `d7`, you need to clear all but the low 7 bits of `d7`.  Your code doesn't do that.  I suspect that's gonna screw things up.

You even have a statement `d7 = d7 & 0x7f;` at the critical point, but for some reason you put it in parentheses and commented it out.  Fix that.  Uncomment and unparenthesize it.

See [RFC 2994](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2994.txt) for more.

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation of `FI()` has the expression `(d7 && 0xffffU) << 9` at the end.  I suspect you mean `(d7 & 0xffffU) << 9`.

Comment: that is a bug, but unfortunately, it didnt fix the implementation :(

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have other implementations that seem to be correct, here are some steps you can take:

- Test each of the components of the cipher, by feeding some inputs and comparing the outputs your code gives to the output the other implementations give.  Test `FI()`, `FO()`, and the tables; those are small enough you should be able to exhaustively test them (on all possible inputs).  Test `FL()` and `FLINV()` on a large collection of random inputs.  Then, test the full cipher on a large collection of random inputs.
- Generate some test vectors from the other implementations that you believe you be correct.  Extract the output after each round.  Compare these testvectors to what your implementation produces.

I would expect that these methods should enable you to narrow down where the problem is.